# How to align text of time in the format of 12:00 using UILabel in custom Table Cell?

Tags: ios

I am new to iOS and couldn't find the correct keyword to find the solution to my problem. I use storyboard for custom table cell and want to have text alignment like the one in Numbers. My result is like this:
[image]

In this screenshot, the: is not aligned among cells. For example, of "12:20" is closer to the left-hand side than that of "09:10"

All UIs in the table cell is created in the storyboard with auto layout constraints of width and leading. The constraints of the UIlabel in question is shown in the following screenshot:

[image]

All I want is the fine alignment like the one in Apple's Numbers app:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because the digits in the new San Francisco fonts don't all have the same width. There is an alternative font with same-size digits that you can select programatically - I'm not aware of a solution for Interface Builder.

To use a monospaced-digits font, do this in your code:

```
if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
    self.timeLabel.font = UIFont.monospacedDigitSystemFont(ofSize: 15, weight: UIFont.Weight.regular)
}
```

or in Objective-C:

```
if (@available(iOS 9.0, *)) {
    self.timeLabel.font = [UIFont monospacedDigitSystemFontOfSize:15 weight:UIFontWeightRegular];
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Now I know that the problem is from the font type not from the  layout or any other attribute of label except for font type. However my app is going to support iOS 8 and the method you mentioned needs iOS 9+. I found a monospaced font ( Courier Bold) instead and it works.

Comment: AFAIK the system font in iOS 8 had monospaced digits by default. San Francisco was introduced in iOS 9, so you can keep using the system font and make the code I posted only run if the device runs iOS 9 - something like `if #available(iOS 9.0, *) { /* set font here */ }`

Comment: I set my deployment target iOS version to 8.0 but ran debugging on iOS 11. So Xcode won't let me build with the method of "monospacedDigitSystemFontOfSize". I am not sure why when debugging, the font seems to be not monospaced. My guess is that in iOS 11, default font is not monospaced again.

Comment: As for " if #available(iOS 9.0, *) { /* set font here */ } " it works like a charm. Thanks

Comment: If this helps, I'd appreciate you clicking on "Accept" :)

Comment: I know I was trying to this "accept" button but in vain. I saw this before from other discussions in stackoverflow. I thought maybe it changes the rule! Guess I was wrong. I am going figure out where to commit the acceptance @@